# When selecting a record from a joined table get the most recent record from the B (joined) table for each A table record if possible

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table of history records and joined to it a table of comments. Both have dates - so a history record is made, and there is a comment table which records comments against that history record.

When I interrogate the tables, I want all the history records, and the most recent comment for each. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be getting the data back as I want, because if a comment is added to an earlier history record, then this query returns the most recent history record (correct) but the most recent comment overall (incorrect) instead of the most recent comment for the history record I'm looking at.

Here is our MySQL

```
SELECT h.id
     , c.id comment_id
     , c.comment recent_comment
     , h.* 
  FROM crm_device_history h 
  LEFT 
  JOIN crm_device_history_comments c 
    ON c.crm_device_history_id = h.id 
   AND c.id = ( SELECT max(id) 
                  FROM crm_device_history_comments  
                 WHERE c.crm_device_history_id = h.id ) 
 WHERE device_id = 147 
   AND crm_history_states_id >= 0 
 ORDER 
    BY h.id DESC
```

**crm_device_history table**

```
id
device_id
crm_history_states_id
userID
dateTime
system_comment
comment -> this field is to be dropped now we have a separate table
distributor_assignment
client_assignment
updated_date
created_date
```

**crm_device_history_comments**

```
id
crm_device_history_id
comment
user_id
updated_date
```

Comment: what are your expected results?

Comment: Add the schema, sample data, current and expected result in your question. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: so I expect to see the most recent history record (h.id) and in that row the most recent comment related to it (recent_comment). What I actually get is the most recent history record but also the most recent comment overall (so the most recent comment in the comment table, not the most recent one that applies to the history record I'm looking at)

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understand you right, so there is one history_record and many comments for it? and you want the most recent comment?

Comment: @SamerAbuGahgah yes almost, there is one device, for which there are history records (table A) and each history record has comments (table B) . So when I recall a history record, I would like the most recent comment for that record.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and please edit the question rather than adding further comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    SELECT 
        h.id,
        sub_query.id AS comment_id,
        c.comment as recent_comment,
        h.*
    FROM
        crm_device_history h 
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
             max(id) as id,
             crm_device_history_id 
         FROM 
             crm_device_history_comments
         GROUP BY 
             crm_device_history_id)
         AS sub_query ON sub_query.crm_device_history_id = h.id
    INNER JOIN
        crm_device_history_comments  AS c ON c.id = sub_query.id
    WHERE device_id = 147 AND h.crm_history_states_id >= 0 
    ORDER BY h.id DESC
```

Comment: almost - the comment I get back for the history record is the most recent comment id against the history record but the recent_comment is still from a different record..

Comment: Got errors, I've put a comma after recent_comment in the select and now I'm getting a 'unknown column crm_device_history_id in ON clause'

Comment: not quite - #1054 - Unknown column 'crm_device_history.id' in 'on clause' . If I swap that for h.id I get records, but only four, and not the recent comment for the history record. This is a head bender!

Comment: @Rich give it a last try

Comment: still no joy. ( Unknown column 'sub_query.id' in 'on clause') Think I'll have to go back to the drawing board....

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT h.id,
       c.id      AS comment_id,
       c.comment AS recent_comment,
       h.*
FROM   crm_device_history h
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Max([date]),
                         id
                  FROM   crm_device_history_comments
                  GROUP  BY id) c
              ON c.crm_device_history_id = h.id
WHERE  device_id = 147
       AND crm_history_states_id >= 0
ORDER  BY h.id DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: ok this code snippet returns an unknown column c.comment in field list..